# JQuery $.post, массив $_POST пуст

Tags: jquery, ajax

Задача: при нажатии на ссылку отправить post запрос без перегрузки страницы

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#test_link").click(function() {                
                $.post("index.php", { name: 'test_value' } );

        });
    });

    </script>
<a href='#' id="test_link" >Отправить</a>
```

при нажатии на ссылку, массив $_POST пуст

Comment: Да вроде бы тут всё правильно.

Comment: А в консоль не судьба заглянуть? Там бывает много интересного.

Comment: $.post("index.php", { data: 'test_value=value' } ); или так

$.ajax({ url: 'index.php', type: 'POST', dataType: 'html', data: 'test_value=value' });

Comment: echo '<pre>'.print_r($_REQUEST, true).'</pre>'; в обработчик и смотрим, что выдаст

Comment: или в Хроме в инструментах разработчика смотрим в Network, и смотрим запрос какой прошел, и какие параметры в Post пошел

Answer (score 1):

И да, в хроме в правом нижнем углу есть крести красный, в нем отображаются ошибки. А еще лучше - FireBug, показывает что куда ушло, откуда пришло.
P.S **ajax.php** замените на свой файл, куда шлете запрос.
А в самом PHP можете **var_dump($_POST['name'])**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test_link").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            cache: false,
            data: {"name":"test_value"},
            success: function(html) {
                $("#ваш_див_для_вывода_сообщений_от_php").html(html);
            });
        });
    });
```